# How to use Array.prototype.filter to selectively filter Json data while renaming object's properties in the resulting array?

Tags: javascript, array.prototype.map

I have a Json that looks like this

```
{
    "score": "1200.65",
    "num_games": "160",
    "wins": "110",
    "year": "2013"
},
{
    "score": "705.23",
    "num_games": "34",
    "wins": "21",
    "year": "2014"
},
{
    "score": "467.12",
    "num_games": "77",
    "wins": "30",
    "year": "2015"
},
```

I'd like to create an array of objects (containing x and y) that can be filtered by a range of years (for example years between 2014 and 2015) for the x property, and a specific property's value as the y (for example "score").
For example, if I filter by range of years 2014-2015 and by property "score", the resulting array should be:

```
[{x:'2014', y: 705.23}, {x:'2015', y: 467.12}]
```

Another example, if I filter by range of years 2014-2015 and by property "num_games", the resulting array should be:

```
[{x:'2014', y: 34}, {x:'2015', y: 77}]
```

How should i go about this? Is Array.prototype.filter the right tool for this?

Comment: First `filter` the objects that you want to select, then `map` them to new objects in the desired format (with `x` and `y` properties).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Filter the array using `Array#filter`
2. Convert the elements of the array to a type of your choosing using `Array#map`

```js
var data = [{"score": "1200.65", "num_games": "160", "wins": "110", "year": "2013" }, { "score": "705.23", "num_games": "34", "wins": "21", "year": "2014" }, { "score": "467.12", "num_games": "77", "wins": "30", "year": "2015" }];

function getFilteredData(data, start, end) {
  return data.filter(function(item) {
    return +start <= +item.year && +item.year <= +end;
  }).map(function(item) {
    return {
      x: item.year,
      y: item.score
    };
  });
}

console.log(getFilteredData(data, 2014, 2017));
```

If your dates are within reasonable boundaries you don't have to convert the year to a `number` but any 3- or 5+ digit years will not filter properly, unless you convert the years to numbers.

If you want a more abstract version of the function you could do:

```js
var data = [{"score": "1200.65", "num_games": "160", "wins": "110", "year": "2013" }, { "score": "705.23", "num_games": "34", "wins": "21", "year": "2014" }, { "score": "467.12", "num_games": "77", "wins": "30", "year": "2015" }];

function getFilteredData(data, filterOptions, mapOptions) {
  return data.filter(function(item) {
    return Object.keys(filterOptions).every(function(key) {
      var option = filterOptions[key];
      if (+option.min <= +item[key] && +item[key] <= +option.max) return true;
    });
  }).map(function(item) {
    return Object.keys(mapOptions).reduce(function(result, key) {
      var option = mapOptions[key];
      result[key] = item[option];
      return result;
    }, {});
  });
}

function registerFilter(filterOptions, mapOptions) {
  return function(data) {
    return getFilteredData(data, filterOptions, mapOptions);
  };
}

var customFilter = registerFilter(
  { year: { min: 2014, max: 2015 },
  { x: "year", y: "score" }
);

console.log(customFilter(data));
```

You could do both operations together using a `for` loop or `Array#reduce`. Which makes the code faster but less maintainable.

```js
var data = [{"score": "1200.65", "num_games": "160", "wins": "110", "year": "2013" }, { "score": "705.23", "num_games": "34", "wins": "21", "year": "2014" }, { "score": "467.12", "num_games": "77", "wins": "30", "year": "2015" }];

function getFilteredData(data, start, end) {
  return data.reduce(function(result, item) {
    if (+start <= +item.year && +item.year <= +end) result.push({
      x: item.year,
      y: item.score
    });
    return result;
  }, []);
}

console.log(getFilteredData(data, 2014, 2017));
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter , Map , Object Destructing can do the job :

```js
const y = [{
    "score": "1200.65",
    "num_games": "160",
    "wins": "110",
    "year": "2013"
  },
  {
    "score": "705.23",
    "num_games": "34",
    "wins": "21",
    "year": "2014"
  },
  {
    "score": "467.12",
    "num_games": "77",
    "wins": "30",
    "year": "2015"
  }
];


const res = y.filter(o => o.year == 2014).map(({
  year: x,
  score: y
}) => ({
  x,
  y
}))

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

First filter the array by dates, then map the filtered items to your required format. You can use destructuring to make the code shorter:

```js
const data = [{
    "score": "1200.65",
    "num_games": "160",
    "wins": "110",
    "year": "2013"
}, {
    "score": "705.23",
    "num_games": "34",
    "wins": "21",
    "year": "2014"
}, {
    "score": "467.12",
    "num_games": "77",
    "wins": "30",
    "year": "2015"
}];

const filterBy = (data, [min, max], prop) => data
  .filter(({ year }) => year >= min && year <= max)
  .map(({ year: x, [prop]: y }) => ({ x, y }));

console.log(filterBy(data, [2013, 2014], 'score'));
console.log(filterBy(data, [2013, 2013], 'wins'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get the objects within your required range, and then use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create the objects from the filtered list.

See example below:

```js
const arr = [{
    "score": "1200.65",
    "num_games": "160",
    "wins": "110",
    "year": "2013"
},
{
    "score": "705.23",
    "num_games": "34",
    "wins": "21",
    "year": "2014"
},
{
    "score": "467.12",
    "num_games": "77",
    "wins": "30",
    "year": "2015"
}];

const get_items = (arr, [sY, eY], prop) => 
   arr
    .filter(({year}) => +sY <= year && year <= +eY)
    .map(({year:x, ...rest}) => ({x, y: rest[prop]}));


console.log(get_items(arr, ["2014", "2015"], "score"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter and map the wanted values.

```js
function getParts(array, [min, max], key) {
    return array
        .filter(({ year }) => +min <= year && year <= +max)
        .map(({ year: x, [key]: y }) => ({ x, y }));
}

var data = [{ score: "1200.65", num_games: "160", wins: "110", year: "2013" }, { score: "705.23", num_games: "34", wins: "21", year: "2014" }, { score: "467.12", num_games: "77", wins: "30", year: "2015" }];

console.log(getParts(data, [2014, 2015], 'score'));
console.log(getParts(data, [2014, 2015], 'num_games'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```